# How do you remove color input padding on Chrome browsers?

Tags: css, google-chrome, wcag

Initially, I tested this on Firefox, on which the padding can easily be removed.
Is there a way to remove this for Chrome browsers as well or is this strictly against WCAG?
I'd rather not use a custom colorpicker.

```css
div {
    border: 3px solid red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

input[type=color] {
    padding: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="color">
</div>
```

Comment: There might not be a CSS-only solution as the `<input type="color">` appearance is somewhat tightly controlled by the vendor. Would you like to explore a solution that involves minimal JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
div {
    border: 3px solid red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

input[type=color] {
    padding: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    width: calc(100% + 12px);
    height: calc(100% + 12px);
    margin: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="color">
</div>
```

A bit of a hacky solution, but it's JavaScript free and should work across all browsers.

Comment: A bit bodgy indeed, but it seems like a stable solution. Thank you very much!